# wistia in native iOS player?

Tags: ios, video, youtube, wistia

could someone please tell me whether it is possible to embed vistia in the native iOS video player ?  We are looking for alternative options to hosting videos on youtube, and have heard some good things about vistia.  Currently our app play a youtube url directly within the native video player.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly are you trying? Embed 3rd party video player Inside iOS video player?

Comment: Right now we are using the MPMoviePlayerViewController player native to iOS.  It plays Youtube hosted video just fine.  However passing a wistia url and it errors out.

Comment: This is the URL to the vistia video that I am trying to play in a MPMoviePlayerViewController but ran into some difficulties.

Comment: https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/5gu0g6pvgu         That's the URL right there.  Sorry about the multiple post.  Seem every enter key generates a new comment.

Comment: So can this be played in MPMoviePlayerViewController?  If not what would be the best way to play it in a native iOS app ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Oops, sorry for another typo.  That control mentioned above should be MPMoviePlayerController not with the view in it.  Essentially as it stands now we have it running by doing a setContentURl to the above url, then invoking control to play as in [pointerMPMoviePlayerController play].  It returns an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess the native player doesn't want to play with that url.

I would imagine that `UIWebView` should open that url anyway.

Here is how you would use it:

```
- (void)loadRequestFromString:(NSString*)urlString
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

And then when you would load the view that has the `UIWebView` in it just call that method.
In your case

```
[self loadRequestFromString:@"http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/5gu0g6pvgu"];
```

Answer (score 5):

I have have been in contact with wistia and in about a month they will release a native iOS SDK that will allow playing their content via the standard AV Foundation framework. They did not give me any further details  (so we have to wait in the release), but most probably MPMoviePlayerViewController support is what they mean.

In the meanwhile they told me to use UIWebview as detailed in the answer from @Pahnev

Edit: here is the sdk:

https://github.com/wistia/WistiaKit

Edit:

Wista now supports native HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) :

Just put .m3u8 behind the wistia hash id and call there embed asset url, this plays natively in the AVPlayer. This looks like this:

https://fast.wistia.net/embed/medias/{hashid}.m3u8

Note however that this requires HLS option to be activated on your wistia account, its possible that you need to contact Wistia support for this!

Comment: I do not believe so

Comment: I am using the same format but I get an avplayer error (unsupported url) do you have any idea why is that